# Can I copy books metadata on my website. Is it legal?

Tags: copyright

Books metadata includes:

- ISBN and other identification numbers
- books title
- authors
- category/genre
- number of pages
- publication year
- publisher
- description (short summary)
- and book cover page

Answer (score 3):

Everything except the summary and the cover art are all facts; facts are not subject to copyright.

The summary and cover art would be subject to copyright. You may have a fair use defence given that all you are doing is cataloguing the books.